# Getting exception "The state of the current PowerShell instance is not valid for this operation." while trying to dispose a Powershell session?

Tags: powershell, visual-c++, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have written VC++ code to connect remotely to Powershell and executing some commandlets. Once all the commandlets are executed, I have to dispose the session. For that, I execute 'Remove-PSSession' and then delete the Powershell and runspace object. But while executing Remove-PSSession, I get the following exception. "The state of the current PowerShell instance is not valid for this operation.". This is my code for disposing the session. I'm not sure if the exception is thrown while executing Remove-PSSession or somewhere else but I'm sure it is thrown in this block.

```
PSCommand^ rmcommand = gcnew PSCommand();
    rmcommand->AddScript("Remove-PSSession $session");
    ps->Commands = rmcommand;
    ps->Invoke();           
    if(runSpace != nullptr)
    {
        delete runSpace;
    }
    if(ps!=nullptr)
    {
        delete ps;
    }
```

Here runSpace is the runspace object and ps is the Powershell object. Since i"m getting this exception, I'm not able to dispose the session. Kindly enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're reusing the PowerShell/Runspace instances for multiple command invocations without first disposing of them? I've seen this error when attempting to do so.

Try creating a new instance of PowerShell and the Runspace for your removal command.